# Form validation for dynamic fields not working in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dom

Hey guys I need help in this code in which I might go mad or something. I don't know why this is not working. I am new to jquery so please help.
When a next button is clicked this function validates the fields. Since I have dynamically added fields I use a for loop and that's where the problem is please suggest some corrections and help me identify the mistake.
Here is the code.

```js
$("#next-2").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        if($('input[name="employment_status"]:checked').length == 0){
          $("#employment_statusError").html(" *Please Choose your employment status");
          return false;
        }
        
        else if($("#wrapmeemployed").css('display')=='block'){
         
         for(i=0;i<x;i++){
          if($(`#organization${i}`).val()==''){
            $(`#organizationError${i}`).html("*Please Enter Name of the Organization");
          return false;  
        } 
          else if($(`#desig${i}`).val()==''){
            $(`#desigError${i}`).html("*Please Enter Name of the Organization");
          return false;  
        }
         else if($(`#workplace${i}`).val()==''){
            $(`#workplaceError${i}`).html("*Please Enter Name of the Organization");
          return false;  
        }
         else if($(`#cadd${i}`).val()==''){
            $(`#caddError${i}`).html("*Please Enter Name of the Organization");
          return false;  
        }
         else if($(`#offemail${i}`).val()==''){
            $(`#offemailError${i}`).html("*Please Enter Name of the Organization");
          return false;  
        }
         else if($(`#contact${i}`).val()==''){
            $(`#contactError${i}`).html("*Please Enter Name of the Organization");
          return false;  
        }

       else{
        

        $("#third-step").show();
        $("#second-step").hide();
        $("#progressBar").css("width","60%");
        $("#progressText").html("Step -3");
          }

          }
          
          }
```

The fields will have names like organization0, organization1 and so on for each increment. When I click next, it simply goes to the next page without validation. I previously tried it with single fields and it worked fine. But I cannot make it work with many fields and particularly dynamically generated fields.

Comment: you should use something like this $(`#organization"+" i "+").val()=='')

Comment: Dude, I tried it without backticks(`) it works. Can you have any other suggestions? Thanks anyway.